# How to be sure of a good solution in hyperparameter optimization

Tags: optimization, genetic-algorithms

I have a very expensive black-box function and at least 15 parameters that I want to explore (usually 5-6 at a time). So far I have tried Genetic Algorithms and Gaussian Process Surrogate Optimization (bayesian optimization). Both methods work fine and efficiently up to 5-6 parameters. However, I am having an issue on how can one be sure that a solution found by GA/GPSO is a good solution, without basically knowing nothing about the output space. I don't really want to go for an exhaustive grid search since even with 5 parameters, it requires incredible amounts of evaluations, yet I cannot come up with anything better.

I would also very much appreciate suggestions/keywords for literature reading, or event different methods for hyperparameter optimizations.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: You can't.  These are heuristics.  There are no guarantees.  They might fail badly; and there's no reliable way to detect that.

Comment: I think in one article, they were showing for GPSO that it converges %70 of times (with toy data set I believe), and making an argument on that. Are you aware of such a method?

PS: I'll send a link to paper / explain it better

Comment: @b.y, those are presumably empirical results.  Also that presumably means that 30% of the time it didn't work well.   Not very helpful if I have a single problem I want to solve; it will give me a proposed solution, but did that fall into the category where it worked well or where it didn't?  No reliable way to know for sure.